# how can i show the corresonding number in the picture from legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used the code  `ggplot(product_info,aes(x=lat,y=lon,colour=factor(location)))+geom_point()`
,picture like this [image]

I want to the number from legend show in the picture with these colourful point together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the text for the corresponding factor using `geom_text()`. Here's an example with the `diamonds` data-set:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price, y=carat, colour=factor(cut), label=factor(cut))) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_text()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could consider `ggplotly` which would provide an easier way of viewing the data

```
library(plotly)
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price, y=carat, colour=factor(cut))) 
    + geom_point()
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]